# Searching a private Blogger blog

Tags: search, blogger

I have a private blog on Blogger, and I want to be able to search my posts, but when I try and do this, I get an error message saying 'The search feature is limited on this blog by owner's request'. People usually recommend changing the option "Let search engines find your blog?" to yes, but this will effectively render the blog public. Is there really no way to search my blog without making it public?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually effectively search even private blogs by entering your search in the NavBar at the top of the screen.  Sadly, the "Search This Blog" widget doesn't work for some reason.

You can find the settings for the NavBar (which is ugly, in my opinion) under the  "Layout" settings of your Blogger blog.

Answer (score 2):

No, that would defeat the purpose of setting a blog private.